# Developing a custom filter for iOS Augmented Reality App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, augmented-reality

Has anyone worked with developing a custom filter for Augmented Reality on iOS Apps in Swift? I am wanting to create a very specific look of a filter for iOS App that blends AR on top of the existing surroundings.

ie. Winter Wonderland theme (snowing, snow on the ground and the buildings around the user)

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to use a computer vision algorithm called SLAM (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping). There are multiple SDKs online that offer this for iOS in Swift, such as: KudanCV (https://www.kudan.eu/download-kudan-cv-sdk/) and ARToolKit (https://artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk).

However, if you want to develop your own SLAM algorithm I'd recommend looking more into LSD-SLAM(link in comment) or ORB SLAM(link in comment).

Also there's an iOS port for ORB SLAM (link in comment)

I hope that helped.